# create video from array of UIImages and save the video to iPhone library. AVAssetLibrary +AVFoundation

Tags: ios4, uiimage, export, avfoundation, avassetwriter

Problem in saving video to iPhone Library.
 i have an array of UIImages,and two buttons ,"convertToVideo"&"saveToiPhoneLib"

```
-(IBAction) convertToVideo
{
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

 NSString *documentsDirectory = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;

NSString *savedVideoPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"videoOutput"];

printf(" \n\n\n-Video file == %s--\n\n\n",[savedVideoPath UTF8String]);

[self writeImageAsMovie:imageArray toPath:savedVideoPath size:self.view.frame.size duration:3];
}


here i'm passing the imageArray and savedVideoPath to the function below


-(void)writeImageAsMovie:(NSArray *)array toPath:(NSString*)path size:(CGSize)size duration:(int)duration 
{

 NSError *error = nil;

 AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:
          [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
                 error:&error];


 NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);

 NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
           AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
           [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
           [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.height], AVVideoHeightKey,
           nil];
 AVAssetWriterInput* writerInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput
          assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
          outputSettings:videoSettings] retain];


// NSDictionary *bufferAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil];

 AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor
              assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput
              sourcePixelBufferAttributes:nil];


 NSParameterAssert(writerInput);
 NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:writerInput]);
 [videoWriter addInput:writerInput];


 //Start a session:
 [videoWriter startWriting];
 [videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

 CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;

 //convert uiimage to CGImage.

 buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[[array objectAtIndex:0] CGImage]];
 [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:kCMTimeZero];

 //Write samples:
......


 //Finish the session:
 [writerInput markAsFinished];
 [videoWriter finishWriting];
}


generate a CVPixelBufferRef here


- (CVPixelBufferRef) pixelBufferFromCGImage: (CGImageRef) image
{
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
        [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
        nil];
    CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;

    CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, self.view.frame.size.width,
            self.view.frame.size.height, kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, (CFDictionaryRef) options, 
            &pxbuffer);
    NSParameterAssert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && pxbuffer != NULL);

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
    void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);
    NSParameterAssert(pxdata != NULL);

    CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata, self.view.frame.size.width,
             self.view.frame.size.height, 8, 4*self.view.frame.size.width, rgbColorSpace, 
             kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);
    NSParameterAssert(context);
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0));
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(image), 
             CGImageGetHeight(image)), image);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);

    return pxbuffer;
}
```

saving to the iPhone library

```
-(IBAction) saveToiPhoneLib
{

 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

 NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;

 NSString *getImagePath = [basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"videoOutput"];

 printf(" \n\n\n-Video file == %s--\n\n\n",[getImagePath UTF8String]);

 UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum ( getImagePath,self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError: contextInfo:), nil);
}


- (void) video: (NSString *) videoPath didFinishSavingWithError: (NSError *) error contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo {
 NSLog(@"Finished saving video with error: %@", error);
}
```

but while saving i m getting error message:-

Finished saving video with error: Error Domain=ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain Code=-3302 "Invalid data" UserInfo=0x1d59f0 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=There was a problem writing this asset because the data is invalid and cannot be viewed or played., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try with different data, NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid data}

please let me know my mistake. thanks in advance

Comment: a code example for the bounty would be nice.

Comment: Take note that each "fix" described here is incorrectly emitting color values with the sRGB gamma slope, the right fix is to use the BT.709 colorspace to write into, as described at this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50880718/how-to-color-manage-avassetwriter-output/54124291#54124291

Answer (score 6):

```
-(void)convertimagetoVideo
{
    ///////////// setup OR function def if we move this to a separate function ////////////
    // this should be moved to its own function, that can take an imageArray, videoOutputPath, etc...


NSError *error = nil;


// set up file manager, and file videoOutputPath, remove "test_output.mp4" if it exists...
//NSString *videoOutputPath = @"/Users/someuser/Desktop/test_output.mp4";
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory()
                                stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *videoOutputPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test_output.mp4"];
//NSLog(@"-->videoOutputPath= %@", videoOutputPath);
// get rid of existing mp4 if exists...
if ([fileMgr removeItemAtPath:videoOutputPath error:&error] != YES)
    NSLog(@"Unable to delete file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);


CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(400, 200);
//    NSUInteger fps = 30;
    NSUInteger fps = 30;

//NSMutableArray *imageArray;
//imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"download.jpeg", @"download2.jpeg", nil];
NSMutableArray *imageArray;
NSArray* imagePaths = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:nil];
imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:imagePaths.count];
NSLog(@"-->imageArray.count= %i", imageArray.count);
for (NSString* path in imagePaths)
{
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]];
    //NSLog(@"-->image path= %@", path);
}

//////////////     end setup    ///////////////////////////////////

NSLog(@"Start building video from defined frames.");

AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:
                              [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoOutputPath] fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
                                                          error:&error];
NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);

NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:imageSize.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:imageSize.height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                               nil];

AVAssetWriterInput* videoWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput
                                        assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                        outputSettings:videoSettings];


AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor
                                                 assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:videoWriterInput
                                                 sourcePixelBufferAttributes:nil];

NSParameterAssert(videoWriterInput);
NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:videoWriterInput]);
videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
[videoWriter addInput:videoWriterInput];

//Start a session:
[videoWriter startWriting];
[videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;

//convert uiimage to CGImage.
int frameCount = 0;
double numberOfSecondsPerFrame = 6;
double frameDuration = fps * numberOfSecondsPerFrame;

//for(VideoFrame * frm in imageArray)
NSLog(@"**************************************************");
for(UIImage * img in imageArray)
{
    //UIImage * img = frm._imageFrame;
    buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[img CGImage]];

    BOOL append_ok = NO;
    int j = 0;
    while (!append_ok && j < 30) {
        if (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData)  {
            //print out status:
            NSLog(@"Processing video frame (%d,%d)",frameCount,[imageArray count]);

            //CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake((int64_t), (int32_t)2);

            CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake(frameCount*frameDuration,(int32_t) fps);
            NSLog(@"seconds = %f, %u, %d", CMTimeGetSeconds(frameTime),fps,j);
            append_ok = [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:frameTime];
            if(!append_ok){
                NSError *error = videoWriter.error;
                if(error!=nil) {
                    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@,%@.", error, [error userInfo]);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("adaptor not ready %d, %d\n", frameCount, j);
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
        }
        j++;
    }
    if (!append_ok) {
        printf("error appending image %d times %d\n, with error.", frameCount, j);
    }
    frameCount++;
}
NSLog(@"**************************************************");

//Finish the session:
[videoWriterInput markAsFinished];
[videoWriter finishWriting];
NSLog(@"Write Ended");

}


-(void)CompileFilestomakeVideo
{

    // set up file manager, and file videoOutputPath, remove "test_output.mp4" if it exists...
    //NSString *videoOutputPath = @"/Users/someuser/Desktop/test_output.mp4";
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory()
                                    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    NSString *videoOutputPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test_output.mp4"];
    //NSLog(@"-->videoOutputPath= %@", videoOutputPath);
    // get rid of existing mp4 if exists...

    AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

    NSString *bundleDirectory = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    // audio input file...
    NSString *audio_inputFilePath = [bundleDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"30secs.mp3"];
    NSURL    *audio_inputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audio_inputFilePath];

    // this is the video file that was just written above, full path to file is in --> videoOutputPath
    NSURL    *video_inputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoOutputPath];

    // create the final video output file as MOV file - may need to be MP4, but this works so far...
    NSString *outputFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"final_video.mp4"];
    NSURL    *outputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputFilePath];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:outputFilePath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:outputFilePath error:nil];

    CMTime nextClipStartTime = kCMTimeZero;

    AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:video_inputFileUrl options:nil];
    CMTimeRange video_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,videoAsset.duration);
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *a_compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [a_compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:video_timeRange ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];

    //nextClipStartTime = CMTimeAdd(nextClipStartTime, a_timeRange.duration);

    AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:audio_inputFileUrl options:nil];
    CMTimeRange audio_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration);
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *b_compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [b_compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:audio_timeRange ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];



    AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
    _assetExport.outputFileType = @"com.apple.quicktime-movie";
    //_assetExport.outputFileType = @"public.mpeg-4";
    //NSLog(@"support file types= %@", [_assetExport supportedFileTypes]);
    _assetExport.outputURL = outputFileUrl;

    [_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(void ) {
         [self saveVideoToAlbum:outputFilePath];
     }
     ];

    ///// THAT IS IT DONE... the final video file will be written here...
    NSLog(@"DONE.....outputFilePath--->%@", outputFilePath);

    // the final video file will be located somewhere like here:
    // /Users/caferrara/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/D4B12FEE-E09C-4B12-B772-7F1BD6011BE1/Documents/outputFile.mov


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
- (void) saveVideoToAlbum:(NSString*)path {

    NSLog(@"saveVideoToAlbum");

    if(UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(path)){
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (path, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError: contextInfo:), nil);
    }
}

-(void) video:(NSString *)videoPath didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo {
    if(error)
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    else
        NSLog(@" OK");
}



////////////////////////
- (CVPixelBufferRef) pixelBufferFromCGImage: (CGImageRef) image {

    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(400, 200);

    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                             nil];
    CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;

    CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                          size.width,
                                          size.height,
                                          kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB,
                                          (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) options,
                                          &pxbuffer);
    if (status != kCVReturnSuccess){
        NSLog(@"Failed to create pixel buffer");
    }

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
    void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);

    CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata, size.width,
                                                 size.height, 8, 4*size.width, rgbColorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    //kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0));
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(image),
                                           CGImageGetHeight(image)), image);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);

    return pxbuffer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That’s simply too much code to check for errors. Make sure you can start the export session, that you really get pixel buffers for your images, that the writer is ready for receiving more data, that the buffer gets appended without errors, that the export session finishes with success and that the output movie file exists and actually contains some data. Only then you can try and save it to the system photo album. Check all the available error information along the way so that you know where the thing breaks for the first time. (Another thing is that you are simply taking code from the web and pasting it together, which is simply *not* going to work for AV programming.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had the same error:

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11823 "Cannot Save" UserInfo=0x193ce0 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try saving again., NSUnderlyingError=0x179e40 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12412.)", NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Save}
```

But only on simulator, when I ran on a device, the save to the photo library worked just fine.

Comment: 11823 error comes when file already exist on the path where you are trying to save the file, so do one thing before saving to the document directory delete the file on that path.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code Below

- (void)creatingVideo {

    //get full path of video file from documents directory
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];
    NSString *videoOutputPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test_output.mov"];

    // get rid of existing mp4 if exists...
    if ([fileMgr removeItemAtPath:videoOutputPath error:&error] != YES)
        NSLog(@"Unable to delete file it does not exits on path");

    //size of the video frame
    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(640,480);
    //CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(1280, 720);

    //frame per second
    NSUInteger fps = 30;

    NSLog(@"Start building video from defined frames.");


    //AvAsset library to create video of images
    AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoOutputPath] fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie error:&error];
    NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);
    NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey, [NSNumber numberWithInt:imageSize.width], AVVideoWidthKey,[NSNumber numberWithInt:imageSize.height], AVVideoHeightKey,nil];

    AVAssetWriterInput* videoWriterInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSettings] retain];
    NSDictionary *bufferAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil];
    AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:videoWriterInput sourcePixelBufferAttributes:bufferAttributes];

    NSParameterAssert(videoWriterInput);
    NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:videoWriterInput]);

    videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
    [videoWriter addInput:videoWriterInput];

    //Start a session:
    [videoWriter startWriting];
    [videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

    CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;

    //frameCount.
    int frameCount = 0;
    double frameDuration;
    double numberOfSecondsPerFrame = appDelegate.delaySecond;

    NSLog(@"**************************video creation started********************************");
    for (int i = 0; i<[self.arrImageDataDict count]; i++) {
        {
            @autoreleasepool{
                UIImage *img1 = nil;

                img1 = [self getImageForVideoCreation:i];

                buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage: [img1 CGImage]];
                if (buffer == NULL) {
                    NSLog(@"Pixel buffer not created");
                } else {
                    BOOL append_ok = NO;
                    int j = 0;
                    while (!append_ok && j < 20) {
                        if (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData)  {
                            //print out status:
                            NSLog(@"Processing video frame (%d,%d) delay %f",frameCount,[self.arrImageDataDict count],numberOfSecondsPerFrame);
                            frameDuration = fps * numberOfSecondsPerFrame;
                            CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake(frameCount*frameDuration,(int32_t) fps);
                            append_ok = [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:frameTime];
                            if(!append_ok){
                                NSError *error = videoWriter.error;
                                if(error!=nil) {
                                    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@,%@.", error, [error userInfo]);
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            printf("adaptor not ready %d, %d\n", frameCount, j);
                            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
                        }
                        j++;
                    }
                    if (!append_ok) {
                        printf("error appending image %d times %d\n, with error.", frameCount, j);
                    }
                    frameCount++;
                    CVPixelBufferRelease(buffer);
                    buffer = nil;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Finish the session:
    [videoWriterInput markAsFinished];

    //get the iOS version of the device
    float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
    if (version < 6.0)
    {
        [videoWriter finishWriting];
        //NSLog (@"finished writing iOS version:%f",version);

    } else {
        [videoWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^(){
            //NSLog (@"finished writing iOS version:%f",version);
        }];
    }

    CVPixelBufferPoolRelease(adaptor.pixelBufferPool);
    [videoWriter release];
    [videoWriterInput release];

    //OK now add an audio file to move file
    AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

    //Get the saved audio song path to merge it in video
    NSURL *audio_inputFileUrl ;
    NSString *filePath = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];
    NSString *outputFilePath1 = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mySong.m4a"];
    audio_inputFileUrl = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:outputFilePath1];

    // this is the video file that was just written above
    NSURL    *video_inputFileUrl = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:videoOutputPath];;

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];

    // create the final video output file as MOV file - may need to be MP4, but this works so far...
    NSString *outputFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Slideshow_video.mov"];
    NSURL    *outputFileUrl = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:outputFilePath];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:outputFilePath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:outputFilePath error:nil];

    //AVURLAsset get video without audio
    AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:video_inputFileUrl options:nil];
    CMTimeRange video_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,videoAsset.duration);
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *a_compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [a_compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:video_timeRange ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
    [videoAsset release];

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3.0];

    //If audio song merged
    if (![self.appDelegate.musicFilePath isEqualToString:@"Not set"])
    {
        //*************************make sure all exception is off***********************
        AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:audio_inputFileUrl options:nil];
        CMTimeRange audio_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration);
        AVMutableCompositionTrack *b_compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

        if (![audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio].count == 0) {
            [b_compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:audio_timeRange ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
        }
        [audioAsset release];
    }

    // Cleanup, in both success and fail cases
    [audio_inputFileUrl release];
    [video_inputFileUrl release];

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];

    //AVAssetExportSession to export the video 
    AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
    _assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    _assetExport.outputURL = outputFileUrl;

    [_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void){
        switch (_assetExport.status) {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
#if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
                [self writeVideoToPhotoLibrary:outputFileUrl];
#endif
                [self RemoveSlideshowImagesInTemp];
                [self removeAudioFileFromDocumentsdirectory:outputFilePath1];
                [self removeAudioFileFromDocumentsdirectory:videoOutputPath];
                [outputFileUrl release];
                [_assetExport release];
                //NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted");
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    if (alrtCreatingVideo && alrtCreatingVideo.visible) {
                        [alrtCreatingVideo dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:alrtCreatingVideo.firstOtherButtonIndex animated:YES];
                        [databaseObj isVideoCreated:appDelegate.pro_id];
                        [self performSelector:@selector(successAlertView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
                    }
                });
                break;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                NSLog(@"Failed:%@",_assetExport.error);
                break;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                NSLog(@"Canceled:%@",_assetExport.error);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }];
}

//writeVideoToPhotoLibrary
- (void)writeVideoToPhotoLibrary:(NSURL *)url
{
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:url completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Video could not be saved");
        }
    }];
    [library release];
}